# Appending list of lists for page rank

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, for-loop

i have the following code for computing page rank of a network. I am trying to create a list of lists by creating a new list in a for loop but every iteration with i, the list goes out of range. I believe the index error is for the loop i but i am not sure how i can modify it to get the lists

```
N =6
nodes=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
in_dict = {1: [3], 2: [1, 3], 3: [1], 4: [5, 6], 5: [3, 4], 6: [4, 5]}
k_out = [2, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1]

# initialising page rank of the vectors
pg_rnk0 = []
for i in nodes:
    pg_rnk0.append(1/N)

pg_rnk1 = []
for i in nodes:
    pg_rnk1.append(0)

#Finding the final probability vector
pgR = []
pgR.append(pg_rnk0) 
pgR.append(pg_rnk1)

for i in range(0,N-1):
    for j in range(0,len(pg_rnk0)):
        if j+1 in in_dict:
            for k in in_dict[j+1]:
                if k_out[k-1] != 0:
                    pgR[i+1][j] = pgR[i+1][j] + pgR[i][k-1]/k_out[k-1]
                elif k_out[k-1] == 0:
                    pgR[i+1][j] = pgR[i+1][j] + (1/N)
```

It gives this error:

```
line 34, in <module>
    pgR[i+1][j] = pgR[i+1][j] + pgR[i][k-1]/k_out[k-1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pgR = []
pgR.append(pg_rnk0) 
pgR.append(pg_rnk1
```

Using `append` here is going to append two lists to `pgR` - the length of `pgR` is now 2.

`pgR[i+1]`

Is going to get above 1 (0-index array) very quickly.

You can use `extend` instead to make `pgR` have the contents of `pg_rnk0` and `pg_rnk1` if that's more your intention?

Here's an example:

```py
colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow"]
fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana"]

colors_and_fruits = []
colors_and_fruits.append(colors)
colors_and_fruits.append(fruits)
# print(colors_and_fruits) --> [["red", "orange", "yellow"], ["apple", "orange", "banana"]] length: 2

colors_and_fruits = []
colors_and_fruits.extend(colors)
colors_and_fruits.extend(fruits)
# print(colors_and_fruits) --> ["red", "orange", "yellow", "apple", "orange", "banana"] length: 6
```

Comment: the thing is I don't want to extend to get the list with all the elements, I want a list that contains N other lists, which is why I am appending. so I need a list [pg_rnk0, pg_rnk[i+1], pg_rnk[i+2], ...] where pg_rnk0, pg_rnk[i+1] and pg_rnk[i+2] are all separate lists

Comment: That makes sense. But, the error you're getting is with `pgR` itself I believe - you're trying to access index `i+1` of `pgR`, and `i+1` can be as high as 6. `pgR` only has 2 elements as it's currently set up with append.

Comment: I think if you were to print out `i+1` right after the last for loop, you'd see `2` and then the error.

Comment: So like I can initialise pgR with 6 other empty lists? I tried doing that it removed the error but its giving me wrong values not the ones I was expecting

Comment: Can you update the question with an example of the result you're hoping for? I think that would help me and other people!